# C - how to malloc struct containing string and array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

say, I have some struct like this:

```
typedef struct node {
    char[32] name;
    int *contents[10];
} Node;
```

I want to initialize a new Node and store it on heap, do I need also to malloc space for name and integers?
However, if I tried to malloc space for them, for example:

```
Node *new_node = malloc{...};
new_node->name = malloc{32 * sizeof(char)};
...
```

I got error says name is not assignable.

Comment: And if an array was a pointer, it would be called "pointer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate space for your struct as `Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));`, that includes space for each struct element.

In this case, that includes space for 32 `char` and 10 `int *`.  So you don't need to allocate space for the `name` array, although depending on your usage, you might allocate space to each element of `contents`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, and to make the code maintainable do it like this

```
Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
if (new_node == NULL)
   allocation_error_do_not_continue();
```

if you check `sizeof(*new_node)` which is the same as `sizeof(Node)` would be `10 * sizeof(int *)` + `32 sizeof(char)` although `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so `10 * sizeof(int *) + 32`.

Not that this requires the definition of the structure to be avaliable in order for the `sizeof` operator to be able to give the size of the structure.

Also, you suggest to `malloc()` for the `name` member, the `name` member is an array and you cannot assign to it, it has enough space for a 31 character string which you can use by assigning to each element, or using `strcpy()`/`memcpy()` to copy a complete array to it. But you can't assign to it and you don't need to `malloc()` space for it because `malloc()`ing the structure already `malloc()`ed both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The usual idiom is

```
Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
```

This ensures that the space allocated sufficient for `new_node`, even if you change its type.  If you use `sizeof (Node)` instead, you are prone to the mistake of changing the type of `new_node` and failing to update the `sizeof` expression.

Your code

```
node->name = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
```

will not compile because `node->name` is not a pointer type; it's an array within the Node type, and the storage is allocated when you `malloc()` for `new_node` above.  So you can just go ahead and use that storage.

Note that `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, and the above would normally be written

```
node->name = malloc(32);  // still can't assign to node->name, though!
```